# Did the drapes in old theatres actually say "ASBESTOS" on them?

Tags: united-states, 1930s, 1920s, building

In many old cartoons from the 1920s and 1930s, whenever there is a theatre scene or similar, and the curtains come down, they literally say "ASBESTOS" on them.

Was this based on real life? If so, why would they have that printed on the curtains/drapes? And if not, why would they do it in the cartoons?

Here is just one example from a 1929 Mickey Mouse cartoon:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not yet an answer, but suspect this is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_curtain with 'asbestos' text intended to re-assure the audience that this theater is safe and was probably a common sight at end of a show of the era, Possibly with a joke due to this safety device being worn and much patched.

Comment: I can remember a time when the safety curtain in a proscenium theatre was always lowered during the interval (to show that it was in working order), and advertisements projected onto it. This was before asbestos was known to be dangerous, but  it said SAFETY CURTAIN on it, not ASBESTOS.

Comment: Asbestos is an *amazingly great* material, apart from that little lung disease problem. Advertising something as "made with asbestos" in the late 19th/early 20th century is a bit like advertising something as "made with carbon nanotubes" today.

Comment: Theater fires (most devastatingly, the Iroquois Theatre fire in 1903) were of significant public concern at this time, and there were also a number of instances of [deadly panics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shouting_fire_in_a_crowded_theater#Background) caused by false cries of "fire" in crowded theaters. With this context, it's easy to see why theater owners would want to take measures to reassure audiences that special features were in place to help ensure their safety.

Comment: My junior high school in NYC had an asbestos curtain for the stage of the auditorium. The word asbestos was stenciled along the edge, and the curtain had a fusible link that would cause it to drop in the event of a fire. The school was built in 1965 and I attended 1966 - 1968, so these curtains remained in use far beyond the '20s and '30s.

Comment: @ZachLipton exactly.  Asbestos was (and still should be) soooo popular because it's stupendously flame resistant.  And the fibers are the best thing yet discovered or devised at reinforcing thin concrete sheets.

Comment: The term "in the limelight" comes from the use of ***4,000 degree*** "lime lights" in theaters way back when.  Asbestos curtains were an absolute necessity before powerful-enough electric lights were developed.

Comment: @hobbs it feels a little funny that you chose this specific analogy, considering that there's been reports that carbon nanotubes (being long and thin by definition) might result, especially if not handled very carefully, in the same kind of lung disease problem...

Comment: Probably worth edit ting the question to make it clear this would have been the **safety curtain**, not the same curtains that are used at the beginning and end of scenes.

Comment: It's the safety curtain, though regulations in some jurisdictions required the safety curtain be raised and lowered at each performance (often before the show or at intermission) in front of the audience to demonstrate that it functions properly. The safety curtain in the Iroquois Theatre fire (while made of a material that apparently might not have been of much use to actually prevent the spread of fire) snagged during the inferno and couldn't be lowered properly. These regulations meant it was not uncommon for audiences in some areas to see the safety curtain in use without an emergency.

Comment: @hobbs It's also the case that not all asbestos is the same.  Some of it is roughly as dangerous as silica dust and other types of asbestos are extremely harmful.  It has to do with the microscopic shape of the mineral.  I think I read somewhere that the worst kind is usually found in South Africa.

Comment: @JanuaryFirst-of-May since the asbestos lung problem is caused by having nanofibers or nanotubes in the lungs, that's hardly surprising...

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can find images of such safety curtains in several places.

[Here](https://www.forgottendetroit.com/national/22.htm) is one concerning an old theatre in Detroit. (copyrighted images so links only).

Another image [here](https://www.staradvertiser.com/2011/09/02/hawaii-news/rearview-mirror/asbestos-was-a-good-word-when-hawaii-theatre-opened/) concerning the Hawaii Theatre.

Yet another appears [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ScarySigns/comments/8w68ay/fire_safety_curtain_in_an_old_theatre/) in a reddit thread.

This Wikipedia article goes into detail on the reasons for fireproof [safety curtain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_curtain)s (emphasis mine).

> It is usually a heavy fabric curtain located immediately behind the
> proscenium arch. ***Asbestos-based materials*** were originally used to
> manufacture the curtain, before the dangers of asbestos were widely
> known. The safety curtain is sometimes referred to as an iron in
> British theatres, regardless of the actual construction material.

Comment: Just note that the real danger of asbestos is in its manufacturing and being near its airborne fibers. The finished product is generally not dangerous unless you like shredding them or sanding them and then breathing in the dust. If it is an already finished product, it's fine. If you need to do stuff with it, like shred it, sand it down (bricks with asbestos), break it down, etc. then it becomes a problem. That's why constructions with asbestos is allowed (it is already built), but you need special permit to take it down, and you can't build new things with it.

Comment: @Nelson, just to add: it breaking is also dangerous and that sounds like a real possibility for example with a fire curtain that quickly has to be dropped in case of fire, (and whose dropping mechanism could have been damaged by the same fire). The danger is not only due to construction especially in items that are likely to break.

Comment: If a fire causes fusible links to drop the curtain before it can be lowered in a controlled fashion, I would think that combustion products would pose a greater health risk than fibers which might be released when the bottom of the curtain hits the floor.  What makes asbestos notable is a health risk is that it can be identified as a causal agent when it causes health problems, not that most contacts cause health problems.

Comment: @Kvothe Still sounds safer than being in a fire.

Comment: I believe some of this dates back to before electric lights, so there was sometimes literal fire on the stage with curved mirrors to provide the lighting.  Also people probably smoked a lot in theaters back in the day, so the fire could just as easily come from the audience.

Comment: Asbestos is a fiber, so these things aren't going to crumble in your hands during normal use. Its processing creates air-borne fibers that is known to cause lung damage, but once weaved into the material, its inert until you do something weird with it like sand it down or put it in a chipper or do something to cut it up.

Answer (score 11):

My brother and I both received one of these in the early 1960's, complete with asbestos sample as shown - except the sample we had looked nothing like the one here, but rather was a sample of fibrous [(tremolite asbestos, as seen at bottom)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremolite).

[image]

My point here is that the dangers of asbestos have been realized only in the latter half of my lifetime - which is nowhere near over yet. Prior to that, advertising the use of asbestos was seen **as a safety feature** - not as a hazard - due to the extreme flame and fire resistance of asbestos and the ability to weave textiles from it. In the early 1960's, it was seen as completely acceptable to distribute fibrous tremolite asbestos to children to foster their interest in geology.

Image of tremolite asbestos (from Wikiepedia):

[image]

Comment: (+1) I can't decide: Should one be more scared of the chunk of asbestos or the chunk of uranium ore kitty corner from it?

Comment: @njuffa [The uranium is pretty much a non-issue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/608581/is-it-safe-to-keep-uranium-ore-in-my-house).  Not sure about the asbestos in it's mineral form.

Comment: @njuffa: In Kirkland Lake we're talking Canadian Shield rocks - billions of years old. The radioactivity from a [pitchblend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uraninite) sample that old will be a fraction of the background radioactivity sitting in your garden: Its composition will be roughly 50-50 [Uranium-238, half-life ~4.5 billion years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238) and Lead-206, with only trace quantities of other (radioactive and not) isotopes.

Comment: Usually the most dangerous sample in these sets was Galena or Calomel, both of which are absent from this collection, so this looks like a relatively safe one!